# CSS: Moving the text down a few pixels but keeping the background still?

Tags: html, css, image, button

I have some CSS buttons that are bigger when hovered over. I have also made the text bigger however I would like to move the text down a few px without messing with the background image being used.

help?

my code looks like this:

```
<div id="nav">
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    <a id="headrush">Beer Bongs</a>
    <a id="thabto">Novelty</a>
</div>

#nav a {
    background: url(Images/Button.png);
    height: 28px;
    width: 130px;
    font-family: "Book Antiqua";
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    color: #C60;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-position: center;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

#nav a:hover {
    background: url(Images/Button%20Hover.png);
    height: 34px;
    width: 140px;
    font-family: "Book Antiqua";
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #C60;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: -3px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#nav a:active {
    background: url(Images/Button%20Hover.png);
    height: 34px;
    width: 140px;
    font-family: "Book Antiqua";
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #862902;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 -3px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: OT: Please add `role="button"` to the links so the browser thinks they are buttons

Answer (score 21):

Use the `line-height` CSS property.

Answer (score 6):

> line-height can work depending on your situation.

Problem with line-height can be if you have a background color and then it will also expand.

For something I was doing, I'm nesting some `divs`

I used   `position:relative; top:20px;`

```
<div class="col-lg-11">
   <div style="position:relative; top:20px;">CR</div>     
</div>
```

> This inline style is ONLY TEMPORARY

Answer (score 4):

Use the following style for link:

```
#nav a:link {
background: #ff00ff url(Images/Button.png);
height:28px;
width:130px;
font-family:"Book Antiqua";
font-size:12px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:bottom;
color:#C60;
text-decoration:none;
background-position:center;
display:block;
position:relative;
}
```

In `:hover` and `:visited` define only what you want to change (`background`, `font-size`, etc.).

```
#nav a:hover {
    background: #f000f0 url(Images/Button%20Hover.png);
}
```

In your code links have different size:
`a` - `height:28px; width:130px;`,
`a:hover` `height:34px; width:140px;`,
`a:visited` - `height:34px; width:140px;`),

That's why you getting different size, position (in `a` you use `margin:auto` - 0px), but for `a:hover` margin has change, so your link also change position.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to move the text down, use padding-top.

Answer (score 1):

`Vertical align does the trick`

```css
.text-to-align {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```